# How to create clean URL

Tags: php

i have a clean url  like this

http://localhost:8081/olshop/detail/celana-panjang-pria-bahan-chinos

in template i'm already create base path url (**top_script.php**)

```
$url  = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$url .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].":8081";
$url .= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$themeurl = dirname(dirname($url))."/";
$basepath = $themeurl;
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $basepath ?>css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

when i open this link
http://localhost:8081/olshop/detail/celana-panjang-pria-bahan-chinos

CSS is called

this result link : http://localhost:8081/olshop/css/style.css

**BUT** when i open link
http://localhost:8081/olshop/index.html

this css not called

this result link : http://localhost:8081/css/style.css

how to fix this ?

help me thank's

Comment: check your .htaccess

Comment: Please post your HTML as it's most likely a relative path issue. For instance linking the file "css/style.css" will add "css/style.css" to whatever directory you're in. So mysite.com/some/folder/index.html would produce a CSS link to mysite.com/some/folder/css/style.css - I imagine fixating a / to the beginning of the path will fix it. Linking "/css/style.css" will always point to mysite.com/css/style.css

Comment: quick fix, copy `http://localhost:8081/olshop/css/style.css` to `http://localhost:8081/css/style.css` ... but seriously, you might want to look into how your file path works

Comment: @JúlioJamil http://pastebin.com/dXzNL84v

Comment: @Andrew then jquery,image too ??

Comment: see: http://pastebin.com/AS1egv8M

Comment: @JúlioJamil not fixed. But i found a solution i'm using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] this result like this $basepath = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/olshop/";